# Posting uploaded from api to other api using restSharp request

Tags: c#, api, restsharp

```
public static async Task<T> Post<T, K>(string url, int obj) where T : class, new()
    {
        var restClient = new RestClient()
        {
            BaseUrl = new Uri(BaseUrl + url),
        };
        var request = new RestRequest { Method = Method.POST };
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var body = new FileParameter
        {
            ContentLength = obj
        };
        request.Files.Add(body);

        var response = restClient.Execute<T>(request);
        if (response.ErrorException != null)
        {
            const string message = "Error retrieving response.  Check inner details for more info.";
            var browserStackException = new ApplicationException(message, response.ErrorException);
            throw browserStackException;
        }
        return response.Data;
    }
```

I am confused on how to post file from one webAPI to other WebAPI using restsharp. To explain the members:

- int obj is file contentLength
- string url is api url

but when I tried to post, it says:

> ErrorException "The request was aborted: The request was conceled"

Comment: Can't you use `request.AddFile` method?

Comment: `The request was conceled` contains a misspelling, so this is probably wrong. Did you mean "cancelled" or "concealed"? I would guess "cancelled".

Comment: yes it is cancelled